# Slim Framework .htaccess HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, slim

I am using Slim for an API which is working really well under http but when I request the URL in https I get a 404 error.

I think it has something to do with my .htaccess file, but I am not sure. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here.

**.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your server configuration the server might serve another directory when accessed via httpd ( eg httpsdocs instead of httpdocs).

You'll either have to change the configuration, copy the content or try to create a symlink from the http directory to the https directory.